# How can I find the bucketid when using GeospatialCoordinateEncoder in htm.java

Tags: java, machine-learning, nupic

The function for finding bucketid `encoder.getBucketIndices()` require a double or string of input value.

However, the input value of the `GeospatialCoordinateEncoder` is `bucket[]` which contain longitude and lantitude, and another double speed.

How can I solve these problem?

Here is the code:

```
public int[] getBucketIndices(double input) {}
public int[] getBucketIndices(String input) {}
```

the problem is the input value for the GeospatialCoordinateEncoder is :

```
int[] encoding1 = encode(ge, new double[] { -122.229194, 37.486782 }, speed);// ge is GeospatialCoordinateEncoder

public int[] encode(CoordinateEncoder encoder, double[] coordinate, double radius) {

    int[] output = new int[encoder.getWidth()];// return  n/** number of bits in the representation (must be >= w) */
    encoder.encodeIntoArray(new Tuple(coordinate[0], coordinate[1], radius), output);
    return output;//
}
```

the get bucketid function

```
int bucketIdx = encoder.getBucketIndices(value)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

we haven't forgotten about you. The answer is that so far this functionality was never developed for the GeospatialCoordinateEncoder in either its Java or Python version. We're discussing the implementation of this now - when we decide something, I'll post the github issue link here (if StackOverflow allows questions to be resolved in this manner).

Comment: Your welcome. Thank you for bringing this to our attention! As it turns out, this is a very complex issue but one of our engineers (Scott Purdy) may have come up with a solution. We haven't yet created an issue for this, but I will look into it and see if we can take a stab at its implementation.